# R Commander ERROR: could not find function "Log"

Tags: r, natural-logarithm

Very new to R, still using drop down menus for my degree. Code comes in next semester im unsure of all this jargon. Basically i need to transform data with Logs and R cant find logs on my laptop. frustrating because it works fine at uni. please send help

Comment: im guessing i dont have the package for it installed but i dont know what one that is

Comment: `log` does natural logarithms in R, used like `log(x)` - this should certainly be included in base R and won't need any packages installed.

Comment: should i reinstall R then since it doesnt appear to be finding it

Comment: R is case sensitive by the way `Log()` and `log()` are not the same.

Comment: maybe [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Karp-Rcommander-intro.pdf) would help